# Event Viewer showing 1372 and 1528 errors after unsuccessful Exchange uninstall (SBS 2003)

Tags: windows-event-log, windows-sbs-2003

We recently attempted to uninstall Exchange 2003 from a SBS 2003 server.

Unfortunately, the uninstall failed with the following errors:

[image]

Event Viewer is now showing the following Directory Service errors together every 30 minutes:

**1373, 1528**

[image]

I've done some research into this but have not been able to isolate the cause of this problem (relatively little information seems to be available regarding these errors).

Does anyone have any ideas on either uninstalling Exchange, or dealing with the cause of these errors?

Comment: What steps did you perform to do the uninstall?

Comment: Just uninstalled using Add/Remove Programs. We never had Exchange up and running in production (just installed).